# Is there a command that outputs ONLY the packages explicitly installed by the user? (ubuntu/debian)

Tags: debian, ubuntu, command-line, apt, aptitude

I have tried searching for this but there seems to be no command that can output a list of packages (ideally in Ubuntu) that I have installed, not including any dependencies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) \
         <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz |
           sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)
```

This gets the correct list of user-installed packages, to a better approximation than the answer from @Stephen Kitt.

Comment: FWIW: Not complaining at all, just leaving a comment FYI: Neither of the answers posted give the correct result on my Raspberry Pi (3B+, Raspbian stretch)

Comment: It seems this answer is more Ubuntu-centric

Answer (score 7):

```
aptitude search '~i!~M!~E!~prequired!~pimportant'
```

will list all the packages which have been installed without being marked as automatically installed, excluding essential and required packages, which is pretty much what you're looking for. `~i` lists packages which are installed, `!~M` filters packages which are marked as automatically installed, `!~E` filters essential packages, `!~prequired` and `!~pimportant` filter required and important packages. The latter three filters will catch quite a few packages installed by default.

On Ubuntu, you can add `!~Rubuntu-desktop!~Rrecomends:ubuntu-desktop` to filter out all the packages which `ubuntu-desktop` depends on or recommends, and which are installed by default:

```
aptitude search '~i!~M!~E!~prequired!~pimportant!~Rubuntu-desktop!~Rrecommends:ubuntu-desktop'
```

Comment: I had high hopes for this, but it seems that this command `aptitude search '~i!~M!~E!~prequired!~pimportant'` lists many files that: **1)** were not installed by me, **2)** that **are** `required`, `essential` and `important`. Tried this on a Raspberry Pi 5 'Lite' that has gotten "too fat"  :)  It seems there should be a better way?

Answer (score -1):

The OP seems to want a list of: `"packages (ideally in Ubuntu) that I have [he has] installed"`.

I read both of the answers here, and neither one came very close to giving me an answer to that same question for my Raspberry Pi. This was puzzling as I was able to get an answer using `bash`'s `history` command:

```bash
history | grep "apt install"
```

This of course requires that one has a `~/.bash_history` file. And obviously `history` won't give package dependencies, but perhaps the commands/files & tools mentioned in the other answers can help with that.