# Debian default installation package list?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to understand how APT works, and here is where I got stuck - who determines what packages are installed, on day-one?

It seems that one of the rules is, based on the current snapshot of the system, `apt upgrade` will install up to the `Recommended` dependencies of the installed packages. So, from a minimum set of 'core' packages and some 'higher-level' packages, `apt upgrade/dist-upgrade` should be able to grow and fill the blanks.

Questions are:

1. Is there a standard list of default packages? (Debian FAQ says a default installation includes packages with priority equal or higher than `Standard`. Does that define the standard list?)
2. Is this configurable or hard coded into apt?
3. Is there a way to go back to this standard list? meaning a single command to reverse all manual installs/uninstalls and their dependencies?
4. Does this standard package list depend on my local hardware setup, aside from architecture? (e.g., what video card I have.)
5. Which config file tells apt to install `Recommended` packages?
6. Suppose sometime after my fresh install, a package with `Standard` priority is added to a repository included in my sources.list file. Will that package be installed on my box next time I run `apt update && apt upgrade`?

Comment: Print a list with installed packages. Time and date is included, to know the "default" packages, from the install date : `$ ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/ | grep list > package-list.txt`

Comment: @Knud that will reflect the last time the packages were upgraded, not when they were installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. See [Is there any "base" Debian metapackage?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/447613/86440)
2. It’s embedded in the Debian installer and the tools it uses (`tasksel` in particular). The installer installs the essential packages and their dependencies, and `tasksel` installs the standard-priority packages if the corresponding task is selected.
3. See [Is there a command that outputs ONLY the packages explicitly installed by the user? (ubuntu/debian)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/190579/86440)
4. No.
5. It’s the default, and can be configured in the APT configuration files under `/etc/apt` or modified using a command-line option (see [Why install-recommends default is true?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/122289/86440) for details).
6. No, you’d have to run `tasksel` again.